# How to add json with fixtures

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine

On symfony I am trying to add some fixtures to the database some of which requires json format.

I tried :

```
$games->setMsrp(
                    {
                        'France': mt_rand(18, 80),
                    })
```

I tried different other variations but in vain

what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the function json_encode to convert it into json.

```
$games->setMsrp(
    json_encode(
        [
            'France' => mt_rand(18, 80)
        ]
    )
);
```

Output: `{"France":29}`